# How are stored handwritten notes from apps in databases?

Tags: database, multiplatform, handwriting, digital-handwritting

At the beggining I'd like to say it's not an emergency :D

I was thinking about project ideas recently. Projects that I could try to create to learn something more, something new or just to leave my comfort zone. I've picked notes app project that support handwritten notes. And here's the first problem, my little knowledge can't come up with idea how to store these handwritten notes in database.
Database or other technologies haven't been picked yet so there is no "How to store it in MySQL?" and so on... just theoretically thinking how it could be done. I was looking in google and here on stackoverflow but didn't get nothing similar, just some questions how to verify or recognize handwritten notes.

Has anybody any idea or lead I could go by?

Answer (score 0):

Here I am assuming your "handwritten notes" are images. A simple solution might be uploading your images somewhere (e.g. [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), but there are countless options out there). Then, in some database you might have a reference to the URL of the image. In your code you can then download the images using the URL and process them as you see fit.

Note: I am making many assumptions here but I hope this helps.

Comment: So asumming that it'd be stored as images then every "beauty" action like highlight, strikethrough effect or just simple erase some part of note would work kind of like paint right? I mean it would be kind of overriding pixels at note image?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question fully. The operations you describe seem to me that they apply to digital text. Are you converting the handwritten text to digital? 

If you want to manipulate the handwritten text itself, by adding/removing/changing something, then yes, you manipulate the pixels of the image.